# Allow /# when oneboxing comments

Tags: bug, comments, chat, onebox

Oneboxing comments in chat is broken when there is a forward slash before the number sign. `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19894363/expecting-a-declaration-c/#comment29596719_19894363`, for example, doesn’t trigger oneboxing while `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19894363/expecting-a-declaration-c#comment29596719_19894363` does.

Comment: When is this an issue exactly? Whenever you copy a comment link, it doesn't have `/#`, just `#`. Where are you getting the `/#` syntax from so regularly that you need it oneboxed in chat?

Comment: @jame The problem is that sometimes it does have `/#`.

Comment: Could you give an example? If I [go to the question in question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19894363), and hover over the comment time to get the link to it, it displays as `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19894363/expecting-a-declaration-c#comment29596719_19894363`, the only time I get `/#` is if I follow your first link which already includes the `/#` so it appears that something is odd in a changing hyperlink depending on how you got to the page. For normal browsing though, I can't recreate it.

Comment: The bug is whatever added a slash to the URL. It should not be there in the first place, as jmac also mentioned.

Comment: @jmac It occurs when there is a new comment and you load it through AJAX.